# Idiom/proverb or phrase about never forgetting wrong doings

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I could have sworn there was a catchy idiom/proverb in english about how you can be kind to something always, but the moment you do one mean thing, it will never forget that (or hate you forever for that). Kind of like Aesop fable with the snake and the farmer in a way.

It possibly was about an animal (dog? elephant?) kick a puppy once and it never forgets? I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: Knows how to hold a grudge.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%20fuck%20one%20goat

Answer (score -1):

***Vindictive***

The [definition from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vindictive):

> Adjective vindictive (comparative more vindictive, superlative most vindictive);
> 1] Having a tendency to seek revenge when wronged, vengeful.
> 2] (obsolete) punitive

I could give a few examples of such characters from movies, but often their modus vivendi is revealed towards the end as a plot twist - and I do not want to post spoilers here. But I can give at least one safe one

A [premise of movie "Down With Love" [2010]](https://www.looper.com/808069/every-ewan-mcgregor-movie-ranked-worst-to-best/) states that

> Zellweger plays feminist author and icon Barbara Novak, who refuses to
> settle down with a man and instead lives life as a socialite. When the
> brilliantly named Catcher Block (McGregor), a reporter with bad
> intentions, gets repeatedly turned down to meet Novak, he begins a
> ***vindictive*** crusade to prove her a hypocrite

Answer (score -1):

Air Force proverb: It only takes one "aw shit" to wipe out a whole page of "attaboys"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [To err is human. To forgive is not SAC policy](https://warshows.com/product/to-err-is-human-to-forgive-is-not-sac-policy-embroidered-patch/)  - Curtis LeMay

Answer (score -1):

**[You fuck one goat...](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%20fuck%20one%20goat)** or **you fuck one sheep...**.

This is based on a well-known [joke](https://www.jokeindex.com/joke.asp?Joke=2586); here's one version

> A big Scot is sitting in a bar, ranting as he downs his pints. He pounds his hand on the bar, says "You see this bar? I built this bar with me own two hands, a finer piece of work you'll newver find, but do they call me MacGregor the bar-builder? No!!" and he downs his pint and buys another.
>
> He points out the window. "See that dock in the lake? I built that dock with me own hands, a finer piece of work you'll newver find, but do they call me MacGregor the dock-builder? No!!" and downs his pint.
>
> He next pointed out the chair and table in the corner, the fence outside, all sorts of similar projects, and says "I built that with me own two hands, a finer piece of work you'll newver find, but do call me MacGregor the handyman? No!!"
>
> He stares into his beer, whispers, "And you fuck one sheep."